# PL-SQL: catch specific error

Tags: xml, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a stored procedure where in a variable assignment involving an xml string, there's a possibility of having the following error:

SQL Error: ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00242: invalid use of ampersand ('&') character (use '&')

I enclosed the assignment in a begin-exception block, where I declared the error -19202, but it didn't work. Catching the -31011 error worked, just wondering if there's a way of catching the LPX-00242 specifically because it is a procedure that parses a big amount of xml messages, throwing a little amount of errors (most of the xml messages are ok), the requirement is specific for messages that have '&' inside, so I need only to catch and sanitize those messages to not overload the procedure, that's already a bit slow nowadays.

As far as I know, the -31011 error might happen for many causes, not only for the & character.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

```
-- The procedure starts before this, but here we have the errors related to xml
-- Error_ampersand was mapped to -31011
   BEGIN
                v_xml := sys.xmltype.createXML(message);
                EXCEPTION
                    WHEN error_ampersand THEN
                    -- Normalize ampersands
                    normalize_ampersands(message); -- this function justs normalizes the xml changing the & for its code
                    v_xml := sys.xmltype.createXML(message);
                END;
-- After this, we save the v_xml in a table among other data processing
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of your code?

Comment: Added relevant part of code, thanks :)

Comment: You could try something along the lines of

if instr(SQLERRM, 'LPX-00242')

This will mean that you are only sanitizing the messages that need it.

Comment: Something I did not get there. `normalize_ampersands(message)` is a procedure. Although it might normalize the message, but it does not return the normalized message. So the following statement should fail again. Of course that depends where is `message` being read from. Am I missing something here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your exception handler you can search SQLERRM for LPX-00242 and handle that in a specific way.

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN error_ampersand THEN
    l_error := sqlerrm;
    if instr(l_error,'LPX-00242')>0 
    then
      -- do it one way
    else
      -- do something else
    end if;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you Rene, this is what I needed because if there's another error that belongs to the same ORA-31011 I should raise it then I do it in the ELSE statement.